# DRF test for APIView returns 400

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I know that it's already a lot of same questions, but it wasn't helpful for me, so I need any ideas where the bug is.
I have a super-simple DRF APIView(all imports are fine):

```
class MyView(APIView):
  permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

  def post(self, request: Request) -> Response:
    return Response({'status': 'success'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

And here is my test (ignore the payload, it's just simplified for this question-post):

```
    import json
    from django.urls import reverse
    from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
    from web.models import User

    class MyViewViewTestCase(APITestCase):

      def setUp(self):
        self.username = 'test@example.com'
        self.pwd = '1234'
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(self.username, self.pwd)

      def request(self, data):
        self.client.login(username=self.username, password=self.pwd)
        return self.client.post(reverse('my-view-url-name'), data=data, format='json')

      def test_my_view(self):
        response = self.request(json.dumps({
            'some-data': 'some-data',
        }))
        print(response.content)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

So, I got here 400 instead of 200. And response type is <HttpResponseBadRequest status_code=400, "text/html">

And response.content is:

```
b'\n<!doctype html>\n<html lang="en">\n<head>\n  <title>Bad Request (400 </title>\n</head>\n<body>\n  <h1>Bad Request (400)</h1><p></p>\n</body>\n</html>\n'
```

So, considering that api view is expected to return 200 w/o any other action, my guess that I'm doing something wrong in test, but can't get what exactly. Any ideas where I might be wrong? View itself works correctly.
Thanks!

Comment: when format="json" you don't have to json.dumps the data. it does it internally. also set DEBUG=True in Django settings in development environment in order to get a more informative error.

Comment: Thanks! I was absolutely sure that DEBUG is already set, but your comment  made me skeptic about that, and I discovered that event if you set DEBUG in settings.py it won't work, so you have to do it explicitly with `@override_settings(DEBUG=True)` or by using `--debug-mode`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! Thanks to Igor Moraru for advice. So my first problem was that I was absolutely sure that tests are already running in debug mode (DEBUG=True is setting). I discovered that it not true actually so you have to do it explicitly by running test with `--debug-mode` option:

```
./manage.py test --debug-mode
```

Or use `@override_settings(DEBUG=True)`:

```
      from django.test.utils import override_settings      

      @override_settings(DEBUG=True)
      def test_my_view(self):
        response = self.request({
            'some-data': 'some-data',
        })
        print(response.content)

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

After that I got more informative error message:

```
DisallowedHost at /api/v1/my_view/
Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'testserver'. You may need to add 'testserver' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
```

Which is easy to fix by just adding `testserver` to `ALLOWED_HOSTS`:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['testserver'] # here may be other allowed hosts, you need just to add one more
```